# Node.js and Express on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wanted to use express with my node.js but now it says that my node.js is to high for express. Now wat i wanted to ask how do I install the right node.js version.

Thanks,

Mkaveli

Comment: check https://github.com/creationix/nvm to switch between node versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is stated in [express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) readme on GitHub:

> **Node Compatibility**
>
> Express 1.x is compatible with node 0.2.x and connect < 1.0.
>
> Express 2.x is compatible with node 0.4.x and connect 1.x
>
> Express 3.x (master branch) is compatible with node 0.6.x and connect
>   2.x